# Magento missing core_email_queue table

Tags: magento-1.7

I've been looking for **core_email_queue**  and  **core_email_queue_recipients**  table for Magento 1.7. Both of them are not there.

The reason I am asking is, sometime Order confirmations send out twice to the same customer after order is placed. Two identical emails with order confirmation. It happens occasionally, and  I cannot find out why the system does it.

Any ideas how I can check the log of all emails send in magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You search wrong way.**core_email_queue** and **core_email_queue_recipients** comes from Magento 1.9.x version. Before M 1.9.x, after order place email send immediately. So you should search any third party module is responsible or not for sending duplicate email.

[Update]

Got to **app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php**, **sendNewOrderEmail** method is fire after order place.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Can you please advice where can I find a log of emails sent after order is placed? I am using sendmail function.

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: Oh got it, but where do the send logs stored on server in this case? var/log doesn't contain any mailing logs.